# Ruby rails paperclip Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using ruby on rails, the `paperclip 5` gem, I use it to upload images to Amazon S3 storage.

When submitting, on my actual host machine, everything works perfect, uploads successfully, **but if I upload on localhost, I get the following error:**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3395ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed):
```

I assume it's because I don't have SSL on localhost. Is there a way to access the S3 storage not using SSL when on localhost? Is there such a setting?

Comment: Let me know the below solution works or not

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Hey, replied!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in initializers and place the below code

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

Comment: Just to make sure you (or future readers) recognize the consequence of doing this, it is a giant security issue.

You are overriding an `OpenSSL` constant. You get a warning when you override the constant.

Practically, this change means that NO SSL verification will be enforced anywhere else you are making SSL requests that expect to enforce verify peer.

If you are just trying to hack a quick onetime solution, ok, but I would NOT want this committed in to my code base. The real solution is to either:

1. Not make the request in development
2. Change validation only for this request

Comment: The solution which I have given is for development mode only.

Comment: This is not good practice, even in development env you actually accessing external service and leaving trust to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to load the certs. If your version of SSL doesn't have them, you can use the packaged certs, as documented here: [QuickStart Guide to Using the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/developer-guide/quick-start-guide.html)

This problem is also addressed in the [aws-sdk-ruby repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/1262)

Ignoring certificate validation as Aniket suggested is a bad idea.

Comment: saghaulor, sorry, but both links are not of any use for me, I'm getting this error from PaperClip that uses AWS S3 API calls internally, recently started getting this error.

Comment: @RedBoy yes, Paperclip uses AWS SDK internally. The error is likely because you don't have the required certs for whatever reason. So the links that I provided indicate how to use the bundled certs from the AWS SDK to address the issue that Paperclip is surfacing. It's not a Paperclip problem, it's the AWS SDK S3 client's problem. So the links that I provided are relevant and useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and the SSL Cert could not been verified because I was behind *Zscaler* proxy. So I followed this [Zscaler help for Ruby > macOS and Linux](https://help.zscaler.com/zia/adding-custom-certificate-application-specific-trust-store). But that did not solve the issue.

So I did the following which resolved **Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError** issue.

- Find cert path of Ruby

```
$ ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
"/usr/local/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem"
```

- This path is actually a symlink which points you to the original location

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem
lrwxr-xr-x 1 username admin 27 Apr 17 23:00 /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem -> ../ca-certificates/cert.pem
```

- Add this path to `~/.zshrc` file for macOS, `~.bashrc` for Linux

```
$ echo "export SSL_CERT_FILE=/usr/local/etc/ca-certificates/cert.pem" >> ~/.zshrc
```

- Don't forget to load the new changes

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```